# Can a HTML/CSS statement be a Javascript Condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Short and sweet, can this be run?

```
if ( document.getElementById('box').style.background = "red") {
    document.getElementById('box').style.background = "yello"
} else {
    document.getElementById('box').style.background = "green"
}
```

**The Problem**

So lets say a box, with an ID of "box", has conditions run prior to the statement above, that changes the background to red, can the if statement then change the box background to yellow? This may be confusing, but in short, **can you use a CSS style condition, to run a block of javascript, to then change the css of that element?**

Comment: I highly doubt background returns "red". Simple test, did you try it?

Comment: The above does not have a focus on Syntax, rather logic, the code above might not run, however is there a way it can produce a similar result?

Comment: The answer is yes. Just try it in the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and see what `document.getElementById('box').style.background` returns. No need to guess.

Comment: So first the equality check operators are `==`, `===`, `!=` and `!==`, here you'll always set the bg to `"yellow"` since your `if` will evaluate `"red"`. Then, style.prop returns a serialization of the value that has been set. And unfortunately, all browsers didn't always agreed as to how it should have been serialized.  And finally, `background` is a shorthand property, so you can even less assume what would be returned as serialized value.

Comment: @Xufox single tests like that are completely misleading. For instance, in FF, `element.style.background = 'red'; console.log(element.style.background)` will log `"red none repeat scroll 0% 0%"`.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, but it already answers two questions: yes, you can use it as a condition, no, you can’t just compare with `"red"`. This is still enough to answer the OP’s question whether there is _“a way it can produce a similar result”_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is yes. But your assignment is not right i guess. What you mean is check background color is currently red then change it to yellow?  I tested in a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r3y72njf/24/. You can also check here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp. One more thing, in your comparison, you must use '==' or '===', '=' mean assignment.

```
if ( document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor  === "red") {
    document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor  = "yelloy"
} else {
    document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor  = "green"
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle, using `==` or `===`, the background in not picked up as "red" - while it does when `=` is set. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry a mistake here, i updated, .style only work when it's inline style

Comment: @sol The `style` property only contains CSS properties that are present on the element’s `style` attribute. `getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor` can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `id="box"` attribute to any visible elements on any pages to make a test.

E.g.

In the element and console tab of Chrome devtool:

1. Add `id="box"` to this question's title.
2. set its background and get the return value.

   `var c = document.getElementById('box').style.background = "red"`. And c is `"red"`. Use `typeof c`, c is a `string`.

So your answer is yes because you can use a `string` as a condition. But be aware of that you may get `TypeError` if the target element with `id="box"` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    if (document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor === "red") {
    
    
      document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
    } else {
      document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = "green"
    }
```

```css
    #box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="box"  style="background-color: red;" ></div>
```